# Get max DataGridViewRow based on Record ID using LINQ

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview, datagridviewrow

I am trying to get the DataGridViewRow with the max record id value.
I am able to get the record id itself but I need to find the row itself.

This is my code for getting the max record id and it works fine:

```
var addedRow =
                dataGridView.Rows
                .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                .Where(r => r.Cells[Glossary.RowType].Value.ToString().Equals(Glossary.RowTypeCustom))
                .Select(r => Convert.ToInt(r.Cells[Glossary.RecordId].Value))
                .Max();
```

I tried:

```
.Max(r => r.Cells[Glossary.RecordId].Value);
```

I am not clear how to the get the row itself so I can give focus to it:

```
dataGridView.CurrentCell = addedRow;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using this.

```
    var addedRow =
            dataGridView.Rows
            .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Where(r => r.Cells[Glossary.RowType].Value.ToString().Equals(Glossary.RowTypeCustom))
            .OrderByDescending(r => Convert.ToInt(r.Cells[Glossary.RecordId].Value))
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

hope it will help.

Comment: This solution works fine but I am not clear how to do it using Max

Comment: MAX returns the same type of variable that the field is.So with `Max` you have to get the max value and then get the value of of row by writing another linq.